# How can I mathematically prove this Matricial Statement?

Tags: linear-algebra

Well I have been studying Linear Algebra and I was attempting to prove some Mathematical Problems. One of them has got me stuck:

> Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ invertible matrix and let $U$ , $V$ be vectors $n\times 1$, given $V^{T}  M^{-1} U \neq -1$. Therefore $U V^{T}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with rank $1$. 
>   Show that $M + U V^{T}$ has rank $n$. (Hint: Use Reductio Ad Absurdum)

I have tried to start the proof by admitting that the matrix $M + U V^{T}$ has two or more Linearly Dependent Columns.

Hence, for  $j$ varying from 1 to n:   $   \exists \alpha_i \neq0  \vert \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i (M_{ij} + U_j V_i) = 0$. But from there on out I tried to split the sum into two other ones and try to work out any ideas but I got none.
Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: By V' do you mean the transpose of V? And how is UV' an $n\times n$-matrix?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question really isn't clear. You can learn how to write math here from our [guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It would also be helpful if you told us what you tried and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: @Servaes If $U,V$ are $n \times 1$ vectors, then $V^T$ is a $1 \times n$ vector, so indeed $UV^T$ is an $n \times n$ matrix (where the product is the usual matrix multiplication). Note that the $i$-th column of $UV^T$ is $v_i U$, where $v_i$ is the $i$-th component of $V$. In general, the product of an $n \times m$ matrix and an $m \times p$ matrix is an $n \times p$ matrix. Try to prove it if you are not convinced! ;)

Comment: Reedited in order to clarify my point :)

Answer (score 0):

Recall [Sylvester's determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Sylvester.27s_determinant_theorem):

> If $A$ is an $n \times m$ matrix and $B$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, then
>   $$
> \det(I_m + AB) = \det(I_n + BA)
> $$

In particular, if $x,y$ are column $n \times 1$ vectors, then
$$
\det(I_n + xy^T) = \det(I_1 + y^Tx) = 1 + y^T x
$$

Now, applying this to $M + UV^T = M \left(I_n + (M^{-1}U)V^T\right)$ we have (noting that $M^{-1} U$ is an $n \times 1$ vector)
$$
\det(M + UV^T) = \det(M)\det\left(I_n + (M^{-1}U)V^T\right)
= \det(M)(1 + V^T M^{-1} U)
$$

Finally, if $M + UV^T$ doesn't have full rank then $\det(M + UV^T)=0$, but this is absurd because then<sup>1</sup> either $\det(M) = 0$, which can't be since $M$ is invertible, or $V^T M^{-1} U = -1$, which we excluded by hypothesis.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm assuming that your matrices have coefficients in a field, like $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$. What we did so far makes sense more in general for matrices with coefficients in a [commutative ring with unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) $R$, but then this last deduction is possible only with the extra hypothesis that $R$ doesn't contain any non-trivial [zero-divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). On the other hand, if this answer doesn't suit your needs and you tell me why, then I can improve on it.